# Who is Aarthi Devanathan and why is she changing so many posts?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange, users, recent-activity, site-promotion

I'm a StackExchange employee and I'm here to improve the quality of the site. I'm editing question titles to improve their readability and just generally working to make this site *even more awesome*.

If I edit a question title and you don't happen to like it, or you felt it was better the way it was before, feel free to revert the question to previous version of the question -- no harm, no foul.

Otherwise, don't mind me, just doin' my job.

**[EDIT]** [Joel Spolsky](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/4/joel-spolsky) has posted [more information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/100137/what-is-the-meaning-of-chaos-is-it-related-to-the-psi-character) about CHAOS Team and what we do.

Comment: Posting this on all the CHAOS monkey's intro posts ;) http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/1461365#1461365

Comment: Mods, if you want to check my work: http://diy.stackexchange.com/users/3312/aarthi-devanathan?tab=activity

Comment: I, for one, welcome our new forum overlord.  I'd like to remind her that as a mildly trusted forum member, I could be helpful in rounding up others to toil in her underground post-editing basement.

Comment: *laughs* Feel free to creepy-stalk me and revert any edits y'all don't like. I'm just trawling through the top 1,000 questions.

Comment: Just wanted to let you know that I did my 1,000 questions (and earned my Copy Editor badge in the process) and I'm just running routine maintenance now; I'll correct top questions and new ones' titles but that's about all.

Comment: The *more information* link is dead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thanks for letting people know what's going on.

This activity has come about as a result of a discussion started by [Joel Spolsky](https://diy.stackexchange.com/users/156/joel-spolsky) over on Meta Stack Overflow:

[Would the Stack Exchange network be better if titles contained complete, grammatical questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/99185/would-the-stack-exchange-network-be-better-if-titles-contained-complete-grammati)

Head over there for more information about what's going on.